# Trajectory visualization with Python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, visualization

I have a `csv` file where each line contains information about a particle's position in time in the following format:

```
time elapsed, x position, y position, z position
```

Each file has a number of these lines, and thus make up points in a trajectory. Each adjacent time step is not necessary equal. I want to create a 3D plot animation that accurately animates the trajectory from start to finish according to this time series.

I've looked into existing animation solutions, particularly the `matplotlib` animation library, but I can't find any example in which the time step of the animation is not fixed, but is rather based on the input data.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `sleep(timestep)` between updating the matplotlib image in a loop.

Comment: I have, but I was hoping there might be a cleaner solution! I'm sure this will work fine though.